# Выбрать строки в DataFrame на основе значений в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Отвечая на вопрос "Какая доля женщин, не проходивших курс подготовки к экзамену, не сдала экзамен по математике?", написал:

```
len(df[(df["test preparation"] == "none") & (df["math score"] < passmark) & (df.gender == "female")])/len(df[(df["test preparation"] == "none") & (df.gender == "female")])
```

Здесь все правильно и верно.

```
df["test preparation"] == "none" - не проходившие курс подготовки
df["math score"] < passmark - не сдавшие экзамен
df.gender == "female" - женщины
```

Но увидел вот такую конструкцию, она тоже правильная:

```
df[(df['test preparation'] == 'none') & (df['gender'] == 'female')]['math score'] < passmark).mean()
```

Уже не первый раз вижу подобные конструкции. Это довольно коротко и приятно на глаз. Помогите разобраться, как она образуется. Особенно не понимаю вот это переход:

```
& (df['gender'] == 'female')](не понимаю вот этот переход)['math score'] < passmark)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут берётся нужный столбец из данных. А дальше здесь используется та особенность питона, что булевы значения `True` и `False` воспринимаются как числа 1 и 0. Соответственно значение условия будет 1, если истина и 0, если ложь. Ну а дальше считаем `mean` - складываем единицы и нули, и делим на их общее количество. Т.е. получается тоже самое, что количество выполненных условий, деленное на количество строк. То есть та самая доля.